# Particle question with 「以内」：「に」 or 「で」

Tags: particles, particle-に

I have seen the next sentences and each one use a different particle

> 数年以内に： Within a few years
>
> 5秒以内で：Within five seconds

Why does one of them use the particle に and the other one で? Could we use the former with で and the latter with に too? If so, does it have to do with the very used or something? I would be very grateful if you could give me some examples too.

Thank you.

Comment: What verb follows each phrase respectively?

Comment: ^ そうですね。。次に来る動詞によるような気が・・・あと、これとか→「５分以内**に**帰ってきてください」と「５分以内**で**スピーチをお願いします」では、意味が違う・・・

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two expressions "数年以内に" and "数年以内で" are almost interchangeable each other. 
However there are slight difference between the two.

> ex-1-1:数年以内に120円/ドルになるでしょう。（注：数年＝5年から6年程度）

=数年以内には120円/ドルになるでしょう。

=1年後か、2年後か、3年度か、4年後か、5年後か、6年後か、はっきりとは分かりませんが、数年以内には120円/ドルになるでしょう。

> ex-1-2:数年以内で120円/ドルになるでしょう。

もし「数年で120年/ドルになるでしょう」と言えば、「5年あるいは6年で、120円/ドルになるでしょう」となる。
このように「で」には、時期をある程度確定的に示す意図が感じられます。

そこで、「数年以内で」は「数年以内に」よりも、若干ですが、時期をより強く示す意図が感じられます。

> ex-1-3:[OK]数年程度で120円/ドルになるでしょう。

とは言えますが、

> ex-1-4:[NG]数年程度に120円/ドルになるでしょう。

とは言えません。

> ex-2-1:Aボタンを押した後、5秒以内にBボタンを押してください。そうしないと爆発します。
>   ex-2-2:Aボタンを押した後、5秒以内でBボタンを押してください。そうしないと爆発します。
>   ex-2-3:Aボタンを押した後、5秒程度でBボタンを押してください。そうしないと爆発します。

ex-2-1でもex-2-2でも、両方とも使えますが、厳密に「5秒以内」でなければならないのであれば、ex-2-1「5秒以内に」がより適切な表現です。

「5秒以内に」は、「5秒以内のうちに」であり、「早いほうがより良い」と言うニュアンスが感じられます。

「5秒以内で」は、「5秒以内のどこかの時点で」であり、強いて言えば「ともかく5秒を越えなければ良い」と言うニュアンスが感じられます。

「5秒程度で」となると、6秒でも良いことになります。

英語のニュアンスは良く知りませんが、「Aボタンを押した後、5秒以内にBボタンを押してください。そうしないと爆発します」を英訳する際に、「5秒以内に」は"within five seconds"でしょうか？あるいは"in five seconds"でしょうか？あるいは"by five seconds"でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

One difference that I can think of is:

> - 「（時間）+ 以内**に** +（動詞）」 -- do something within [period of time] from now
> - 「（時間）+ 以内**で** +（動詞）」 -- take less than [period of time] to do something

For example:

「救急車はそこに３０分以内**で**到着します。」
-- It takes less than 30 minutes for an ambulance to arrive there.
「救急車はそこに３０分以内**に**到着します。」
-- The ambulance will arrive there within 30 minutes (from now).

「５分以内**で** (not に) スピーチをしてください。」
-- Please give a speech of up to 5 minutes in length.

「１時間以内**に** (not で) １億円を用意しろ、さもなくば娘の命はない。」
-- Come up with 100 million yen within 1 hour (from now), or you'll never see your daughter again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point would be the difference of the role between に and で.

When it indicates length, で is used like 一か月で犬小屋を作った(I made a dog house in a month).

When you indicate a point of time, に is used like 明日の朝に会いましょう(Let's meet tomorrow morning).

So When it indicates determinate time like within a month, I feel に indicates a point within time but で indicates a range within time. For example, 一か月以内に海に行きたい is more natural than 一か月以内で海に行きたい because the time he wants to go to the sea is a point of time.